# How can we add an image field to PDF document?

Tags: image, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a form in `pdf` document where I have added some `checkboxes` and some `input` fields where I can get the input from the user but now I want the `user` to be able to upload their picture to the `pdf` document therefore I need to add an `image` field to the `form` where the user needs to click and upload their image to the file. Is there any free way to do this?

I googled a lot but did not find any convenient way to do it.
I am sorry this question is not related to programming but I have this issue and want to get it resolved through the help of `stackoverflow` community.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should mention how you want to add that field. You say your question is not programming related, so you apparently are not looking for a way to write a program that does that. Are you doing this manually, using some hex editor?

Comment: @mkl : Yes, I want to add the field through a free online tool, I have already added the input fields through online tools